# Concurrency check when updating using GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

With this SqlDataSource, How can i be sure that the data I'm going to update is not modified in the meantime when i fetched data and when i'm about to make the update.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ChartDatabaseConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Student]" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Student] SET [StudentName] = @StudentName, [DOB] = @DOB, [Age] = @Age, [Course] = @Course, [City] = @City, [MobileNo] =
 @MobileNo WHERE [StudentID] = @StudentID">
```

Is there any GridView method Or Any Parameter I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a propery on `SqlDataSource` named [`ConflictDetection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.conflictdetection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Setting that property to [`CompareAllValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.conflictoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may do the trick for you.